# nginx not serving images with long name and spaces 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx, webserver

some images on nginx server getting error 403 forbidden.

for example if upload files with name `test.png` everything is fine, but if upload file with name `Screen Shot 2022-05-27 at 15.01.42.png` i'm getting error `403 forbidden`.

```
    location ~ ^/srv/files/(.+\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|otf|eot|svg|tiff|psd|raw|mp4|pdf))$ {
            alias /srv/files/$1;
            error_log    /var/log/nginx/srv.error.log debug;
            access_log   /var/log/nginx/srv.access.log main;
#           access_log off;
            expires 1d;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload" always;
```

Comment: I think it's because of spaces in your file name. Check if other long name files with no spaces work fine?

Comment: yes, i'm checked right now, getting error because of the space. long name doesn't matter

Comment: browser replaces hello from.png to (hello%20from).png

Comment: for further information refer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/858784/nginx-serve-static-html-content-with-whitespace-in-filename)